# How to import time series in rda/RData file using quantmod R

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to save stock time series in a **rda/RData** file and then call it in quantmod.

I have downloaded and saved AAPL's stock time series as an **rda/RData** file using this code

```
data=getSymbols("AAPL",auto.assign=F)
save(data,file="AAPL.rda")
#Cleared environment
```

Now how should I call this **rda/RData** file using quantmod. tried this

```
getSymbols('AAPL',src='rda')
```

but its showing this error

> Error in fr[, -1] : incorrect number of dimensions

next question is if I have multiple rda files(like AAPL.rda,GOOG.rda,F.rda) how should I call these files in an environment using quantmod.

**EDITED**

I missied this point I want to call from **getSymbols()** instead of **load()** because I need more control to the time series

for example

```
 getSymbols('AAPL',src='rda',from="2010-02-02",to="2011-01-01")
```

Comment: After saving the file, clear the environment then repeat the code

Comment: ok I just tried this and I didn't get the error so I tried totally closing R and reopening it and I still don't get the error. That's also a weird error for you to be getting.. I feel like something is missing from this picture. Can you try it with a different ticker symbol that you've never used before? and make sure your working directory is where you saved it and is the same when you go to load it

Comment: I am still geting the same error. I am using ubutnu 14.04 may be its because of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantmod/quantmod.pdf) of `getSymbols()` in the `quantmod` package:

> Current src methods available are: yahoo, google, MySQL, FRED, csv,
>   RData, and oanda.

What you can do to save a file and load it afterwards is, e.g., the following:

```
data <- getSymbols("AAPL",auto.assign=FALSE)
save(data,file="AAPL.rda")
```

(start a new R session, or clear environment etc.)

To retrieve the previously saved data we can use

```
load(file = "AAPL.rda")
```

Now the data set `data` with the AAPL time series is available again.
Note that one should **not** assign the output of `load()` to an object, like `data <- load(file=...)`. This is a common mistake that often creates confusion. The `data` file in this example is restored with the `load()` function itself.

A subset of the loaded data can be obtained, e.g., with

```
data['2010-02-02::2011-01-01']
#> head(data['2010-02-02::2011-01-01'])
#           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
#2010-02-02    195.91    196.32   193.38     195.86   174585600      25.75517
#2010-02-03    195.17    200.20   194.42     199.23   153832000      26.19832
#2010-02-04    196.73    198.37   191.57     192.05   189413000      25.25416
#2010-02-05    192.63    196.00   190.85     195.46   212576700      25.70257
#2010-02-08    195.69    197.88   194.00     194.12   119567700      25.52636
#2010-02-09    196.42    197.50   194.75     196.19   158221700      25.79856
```

---

**Edit:**

Below is an example that illustrates how `.RData` files can be used:

```
saveSymbols(getSymbols("AAPL"), file.path=getwd()) #saves 'AAPL.RData' in working directory
rm(AAPL)
data <- getSymbols("AAPL", src="RData", extension="RData", auto.assign=FALSE)
#> head(data)
#           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
#2007-01-03     86.29     86.58    81.90      83.80   309579900      11.01952
#2007-01-04     84.05     85.95    83.82      85.66   211815100      11.26411
#2007-01-05     85.77     86.20    84.40      85.05   208685400      11.18389
#2007-01-08     85.96     86.53    85.28      85.47   199276700      11.23912
#2007-01-09     86.45     92.98    85.15      92.57   837324600      12.17276
#2007-01-10     94.75     97.80    93.45      97.00   738220000      12.75529
```

---

**Further Edit:**

I can confirm the statements made by @Hack-R in the comments. Although the documentation describes this in a rather hidden way, by reading the section about `getSymbols.rda()` it becomes clear that the `src="rda"` option is still supported as a valid parameter for `getSymbols()`. Indeed it still works on my installation:

```
data <- getSymbols("AAPL",auto.assign=FALSE)
save(data,file="AAPL.rda")
rm(data)
data <- getSymbols("AAPL", src="rda", auto.assign=FALSE)

#>head(data)
#           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
#2007-01-03     86.29     86.58    81.90      83.80   309579900      11.01952
#2007-01-04     84.05     85.95    83.82      85.66   211815100      11.26411
#2007-01-05     85.77     86.20    84.40      85.05   208685400      11.18389
#2007-01-08     85.96     86.53    85.28      85.47   199276700      11.23912
#2007-01-09     86.45     92.98    85.15      92.57   837324600      12.17276
#2007-01-10     94.75     97.80    93.45      97.00   738220000      12.75529
```

In conclusion, after a couple of variants of saving, loading, and manipulating time series with quantmod we seem to be back to square one: The error described in the OP does not seem to be reproducible.

Comment: hey I edited the question. Please see the edited one. As you mentioned in your answer RData is available then can you show me how to do with RData instead of rda

Comment: Hey I redownloded the AAPL as RData file and tried this code `getSymbols('AAPL',src='RData')` but its giving this error file  `AAPL.rda  does not exist  in   ....skipping
[1] "AAPL"`

Comment: @Eka I think he wants you to save it as `RData` instead of `.rda`. Though personally `rda` worked fine for me anyway.

Comment: @RHertel  how can I load it in an enviroment; tried this `data <- new.env()     getSymbols("AAPL", src = "rda", env = data, auto.assign = F) ` it loads the rda file but dosent load it to the data enviorment. any idea why its happening. Should I ask this as another question?

Comment: @Eka Thanks for accepting my answer. I think it might indeed be better to ask a separate question concerning your last comment. I generally use `auto.assign=FALSE` and I *suspect* that this option is not compatible with exporting the data to a specific environment, as it returns the data directly to the caller. But to be sure and to obtain other users' input, it may be good to increase the visibility of this new question in a new post. Sorry that I can't be more helpful.